# selector is not called 2 tapgesture

Tags: ios, uiview, swift2, selector, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a view, but when I click it the method is not being called.

```
func addTapGestuere(uiview: UIView) {

        let tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("cardTapped:"))
        uiview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)   
    }
```

I run this on the `viewDidload`

```
self.addTapGestuere(self.Card1View)
self.addTapGestuere(self.Card2View)
```

I put a break point on the method

```
cardTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
}
```

but when I click on the image the method isnt called. I have user interaction enabled for all the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful about the following:

1. The `UIView` you are trying to add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to true:

   `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true`
2. The `UIView` you are trying to get the tap to has no other views covering it. Use the View Debugger to confirm this.
3. Most importantly, make sure you are adding the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the correct `UIView`. Adding it to `self.view` will add it to the `UIViewController`'s view.

As a side note: You can add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` using the `Inetrface Builder` itself, then connecting `IBAction` for the same. Will reduce the probability of simple mistakes.